# How do I get my tabs to line up properly using CSS?

Tags: html, css

This should be an easy one for someone. I am creating tabs with CSS (please, I don't need suggestions for how to make them look better, this is what my customer wants). As you can see in the image below, my tabs and my "tab bar" don't line up. I do not know why.

[image]

The HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="prototype.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="content">
                <div id="tabs">
                    <span id="tab0" class="tab">
                        No Circuit
                    </span>
                    <span id="tab1" class="tab">
                        Digital Inputs
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
<html>
```

The CSS:

```
#container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
    position: float;
    width: 900px;
}

#content {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    position: relative;
    width: 868px;
}

#tabs {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
}

.tab {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: What *should* it look like? I'm going to guess and write an answer anyway, but it's just a guess..

Comment: I just want the tabs and the tab bar to line up, no overlap or gaps.

Comment: (I removed that comment because I realised you'd look at my answer anyway).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try: http://jsfiddle.net/dYz9k/1/

```
.tab {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 0;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding: 3px;
    display: inline-block
}
```

I set `display: inline-block`, and removed the `margin-top` and `border-top`.

`display: inline-block` allows the padding to work as you're expecting.

Answer (score 4):

Hm..not 100% certain if that'a what you're asking, but try setting padding:0 on .tab class

Comment: That solves the problem; however, then I end up with more cramped tabs.

Comment: check out my list solution, it does exactly what you want

Comment: I'm going with @thirtydot because it's not a list solution. This will all end up being built dynamically and I don't need accessibility, so going with a list is just too complicated.

Comment: @Nik: maybe try solving this by applying line-height: __em; to your tab class, of course instead of underscores apply some numbers, you'll figure easier which ones.

Comment: @Freelancer, I am using @thirtydot's solution because it simply keeps the padding.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a list, better for Accessibility

Example here http://jsfiddle.net/hdhkn/

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="content">
                <ul id="tabs">
                    <li id="tab0" class="tab">
                        No Circuit
                    </li>
                    <li id="tab1" class="tab">
                        Digital Inputs
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
<html>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
    position: float;
    width: 900px;
}

#content {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    position: relative;
    width: 868px;
}

#tabs {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    list-style:none;
    height:40px;
}

.tab {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-top:none;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding: 3px;
    float:left;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Yup, `ul`/`li` is a better choice here. Instead of setting `height: 40px`, you should properly clear the floats. Replace `height: 40px` with `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: yeah, I would have, but did not want to change all the markup

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/BNPsg/) what you want to accomplish? Or do you want your tabs(`.tab`) to be on top of `#tabs`?

[image]

I've added `overflow: hidden` to `#tabs` and changed the `margin-left` to `margin-right`.

Comment: Because I haven't specified one, and I'm using Chrome :).

Comment: because of the overflow hidden, it is there, just hidden!!

Answer (score 1):

You're putting padding on inline elements (the tabs), that always causes unexpected results.

Cleaned it up a bit for you.

```
    <html>
        <head>
        <style type="text/css">

    #container {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: 15px;
        width: 900px;
    }

    #content {
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin-top: 15px;
        padding: 15px;
        width: 868px;
    }

    #tabs {
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .tab {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-bottom:0px solid black;
        margin-left: 5px;
        margin-top: 2px;
        padding: 3px;
        float:left;
    }
    .clear {
        display:block;
        clear:both;
    }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="content">
                    <div id="tabs">
                        <span id="tab0" class="tab">
                            No Circuit
                        </span>
                        <span id="tab1" class="tab">
                            Digital Inputs
                        </span>
                        <span class="clear"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    <html>
```